# How do i check the length of a number in python 3?

Tags: python

What I want to do is determine the length of a number in python, for example I had a user input:

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
print(num)
```

and the output was 1943, how will I get python to return the length of that, which is 4 in this example?

As well as that, how do I save it to a string? I tried this:

```
t = len(byte)
```

It just returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bytes.py", line 10, in <module>
start()
File "bytes.py", line 5, in start
t = len(bytes)
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Comment: for your edit, what is `t`, and what is `byte`?

Comment: If the question has been answered then accept that answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check its length as string:

`print(len(str(num)))`

#### Examples:

```
>>> num = 123123
>>> print(len(str(num)))
6

>>> num = 10293847586
>>> print(len(str(num)))
11
```

Comment: @sshashank lol the funny thing is, it was a string in the first place.

Comment: this isn't a cast but you create a new string object.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, Thank you! I have changed the wording of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(len(num))
```

You already have a string. Just call `len` on it to get the length.

Your code failed because you typed `len(bytes)`. Particularly, take note of that final `s`. `bytes` is the type Python uses to represent sequences of bytes; it's not the variable you used to store your input.

Comment: Looked and found how:    digits = int(math.log10(num))+1